# manipulating a text datatype representing an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following is a stored value for datatype defined as `text`

```
text_field = "[{\"shop_id\"=>110, \"budget\"=>\"040\"}, {\"shop_id\"=>111, \"budget\"=>173}, {\"shop_id\"=>141, \"budget\"=>344}, {\"shop_id\"=>142, \"budget\"=>\"020\"}, {\"shop_id\"=>144, \"budget\"=>\"220\"}]"
```

Thus defined, it is for all intents and operational purposes a ruby `String` class.  The contents represent an array of hashes.

How can this string become the array of hashes so that one can call

```
text_field_array.each do |hash|
  shop = Shop.find(hash[shop_id])
  shop_budget = shop.budget + hash[budget]
  [...]
end
```

Comment: How do you come up with the value of `text_field`?

Comment: the data is generated by the application itself (not external user); it can contain thousands of hashes. The db not being postgresql, it could not be stored as datatype array.

Comment: You could try saving them as JSON and then parsing the saved value.

Comment: @SebastianPalma is right, use JSON. AFAIK newer versions of MySQL have native JSON support so if that's your database then you could use JSON instead of a stringified Hash. If you're using something else you could still use JSON and parse it in Ruby. Or break it out into a separate table. Your problem isn't really "how do I parse this string?", your problem is "why do I have data in this cumbersome format?".

Comment: valid observations.  This was a consideration, but this legcy application's production server is running a version prior to 5.7; when that context is decided upon, this is an avenue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`eval`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel:eval)

```rb
> eval(text_field)
=> [{"shop_id"=>110, "budget"=>"040"},
 {"shop_id"=>111, "budget"=>173},
 {"shop_id"=>141, "budget"=>344},
 {"shop_id"=>142, "budget"=>"020"},
 {"shop_id"=>144, "budget"=>"220"}]
```

NOTE: Be careful about it. Make sure the text doesn't have malicious code in the string. Read more about it here https://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/security.html